# jquery selector html undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access the `innerHtml` of a `div` by `id` using `jQuery`. It returns an object but empty `text()` and undefined `html()`.

I am trying to get the `1` inside the div with id=`someId`.

```
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "div1";
    div.innerHTML = "<div id='someId'>1</div><div>anotherdiv</div>";

    alert($('#div1 #someId'));
    alert($('#div1 #someId').text());
    alert($('#div1 #someId').html());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created div is not added to the DOM at all. After adding to the DOM .text() or .html() will work.

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "div1";
div.innerHTML = "<div id='someId'>1</div><div>anotherdiv</div>";
document.body.appendChild(div);


alert($('#div1 #someId'));
alert($('#div1 #someId').text());
alert($('#div1 #someId').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```